# Loading jenkinsFile from local disk and run the Declarative pipeline on the same Agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am setting up a Jenkins locally without SCM.

I have several Pipelines with the same JenkinsFile but with different parameters.

I would like to centralize the JenkinsFile for all the pipelines.

I found a solution originally for a scripted pipeline:

```
node {
  load "/path/to/local/jenkinsFile.groovy"
}
```

The problem here is that Jenkins needs two agents to run the previous pipeline (one for the loading node, the other to run the pipeline) and both of them won't finish before the end of the pipeline.

Since I have multiples pipelines cron triggered, at some point, all the agents are busy to load the pipeline files, but since there is no more available agent to run each pipeline, the Jenkins process is stuck and then there is a bottleneck in the job queue.

For solutions I imagine:

- How can I release the agent after the load of the pipeline?
- Is there a way at the first pipeline (load the jenkinsFile) to keep an agent for running the pipeline?

Comment: have you solved problem? I'm also trying with this approach.

Comment: I don't ... I used double agent. Since I am a bit more experienced with jenkins, I realized i really didn't use it as i was meant to be ! 
If you had found a solution, i am interested !